# ViewController does not conform to protocol on Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having an issue with calling a delegate in my class. I have a SideBarTableController and SideBar.swift file.It was working fine until I logged off and back in. Here is the code. It keeps telling me that 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'SideBarDelegate'. I'm new to programming so sorry in advance if this is vague. Anything will help thanks!

```
import UIKit
import iAd

class ViewController: UIViewController, SideBarDelegate {  -----This is where the error is happening


@IBOutlet var menuTab: UIButton!        // Menu Tab
@IBOutlet var businessButton: UIButton! // Business Button
@IBOutlet var adBanner: ADBannerView!   // Banner Ad
@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!   // Main Image in middle
var topHeader: UIImageView!             // Utility header

var sideBar:SideBar = SideBar()         // Side Bar


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    // Function for menu
   // menuTab.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    func menuTab(sender: UIButton){
        sideBar = SideBar(sourceView: self.view, menuItems: ["Home", "Business Directory", "Classifieds", "Featured News", "Jobs", "Restaurants", "Sports"])
        sideBar.delegate = self        }

    // Gives the screen dimensions
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width
    let screenHeight = screenSize.height


    // Side bar action and text
    sideBar = SideBar(sourceView: self.view, menuItems: ["Home", "Business Directory", "Classifieds", "Featured News", "Jobs", "Restaurants", "Sports"])
    sideBar.delegate = self


    // Utility Background
    var topHeader = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 17))
    topHeader.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
    self.view.addSubview(topHeader)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// Side Bar funcion
func sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(index: Int) {
    if index == 0{
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        imageView.image = nil
    } else if index == 1{
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image2")
    }
}
// Status bar style (white)
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
}


}
```

Here is where I called the SideBarDelegate

```
import UIKit

@objc protocol SideBarDelegate{
    func sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(index:Int)
    func sideBarWillClose()
    func sideBarWillOpen()
}

class SideBar: NSObject, SideBarTableViewControllerDelegate {

    let barWidth:CGFloat = 176.0
    let sideBarTableViewTopInset:CGFloat = 64.0
    let sideBarContainerView:UIView = UIView()
    let sideBarTableViewController:SideBarTableViewController = SideBarTableViewController()
    let originView:UIView!

    var animator:UIDynamicAnimator!
    var delegate:SideBarDelegate?
    var isSideBarOpen:Bool = false

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    init(sourceView:UIView, menuItems:Array<String>){
        super.init()
        originView = sourceView
        sideBarTableViewController.tableData = menuItems

        setupSideBar()

        animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: originView)

        let showGestureRecognizer:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSwipe:")
        showGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
        originView.addGestureRecognizer(showGestureRecognizer)

        let hideGestureRecognizer:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSwipe:")
        hideGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
        originView.addGestureRecognizer(hideGestureRecognizer)


    }


    func setupSideBar(){

        sideBarContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(-barWidth - 1, originView.frame.origin.y, barWidth, originView.frame.size.height)
        sideBarContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        sideBarContainerView.clipsToBounds = false

        originView.addSubview(sideBarContainerView)

        let blurView:UIVisualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light))
        blurView.frame = sideBarContainerView.bounds
        sideBarContainerView.addSubview(blurView)


        sideBarTableViewController.delegate = self
        sideBarTableViewController.tableView.frame = sideBarContainerView.bounds
        sideBarTableViewController.tableView.clipsToBounds = false
        sideBarTableViewController.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
        sideBarTableViewController.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        sideBarTableViewController.tableView.scrollsToTop  = false
        sideBarTableViewController.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(sideBarTableViewTopInset, 0, 0, 0)

        sideBarTableViewController.tableView.reloadData()

        sideBarContainerView.addSubview(sideBarTableViewController.tableView)

    }


    func handleSwipe(recognizer:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        if recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left{
            showSideBar(false)
            delegate?.sideBarWillClose()

        }else{
            showSideBar(true)
            delegate?.sideBarWillOpen()
        }

    }


    func showSideBar(shouldOpen:Bool){
        animator.removeAllBehaviors()
        isSideBarOpen = shouldOpen

        let gravityX:CGFloat = (shouldOpen) ? 0.5 : -0.5
        let magnitude:CGFloat = (shouldOpen) ? 20 : -20
        let boundaryX:CGFloat = (shouldOpen) ? barWidth : -barWidth - 1


        let gravityBehavior:UIGravityBehavior = UIGravityBehavior(items: [sideBarContainerView])
        gravityBehavior.gravityDirection = CGVectorMake(gravityX, 0)
        animator.addBehavior(gravityBehavior)

        let collisionBehavior:UICollisionBehavior = UICollisionBehavior(items: [sideBarContainerView])
        collisionBehavior.addBoundaryWithIdentifier("sideBarBoundary", fromPoint: CGPointMake(boundaryX, 20), toPoint: CGPointMake(boundaryX, originView.frame.size.height))
        animator.addBehavior(collisionBehavior)

        let pushBehavior:UIPushBehavior = UIPushBehavior(items: [sideBarContainerView], mode: UIPushBehaviorMode.Instantaneous)
        pushBehavior.magnitude = magnitude
        animator.addBehavior(pushBehavior)


        let sideBarBehavior:UIDynamicItemBehavior = UIDynamicItemBehavior(items: [sideBarContainerView])
        sideBarBehavior.elasticity = 0.3
        animator.addBehavior(sideBarBehavior)

    }

    func sideBarControlDidSelectRow(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        delegate?.sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    }

}
```

Comment: please, show the line where the compiler finds the error...

Comment: Can you also show your declaration of the SideBarDelegate protocol?

Comment: BTW, unrelated to your question, but you are instantiating `sideBar` twice, once in the variable declaration and then again in `viewDidLoad`. You probably want to get rid of one of those (e.g. define the variable as `var sideBar: SideBar!` and then let `viewDidLoad` instantiate it).

Comment: Here is what you guys asked for. Oh and thanks for the heads up I didnt see that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `SideBarDelegate` protocol specifies some methods that must be implemented in order to conform to that protocol. So look at the definition of that protocol, identify what methods are defined therein, and then implement them in your `ViewController` class.

It's possible you missed one of the functions defined in that protocol, or perhaps you mistyped something in the definition of `sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex`. We cannot say without seeing the definition of this protocol.

---

Update:

You subsequently supplied the definition of your protocol. It defines two additional functions that you have not implemented in your view controller:

```
func sideBarWillClose()
func sideBarWillOpen()
```

You also must implement these two functions in your view controller (even if you put nothing into them).

Comment: Here is where i call the protocol.                           @objc protocol SideBarDelegate{
    func sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(index:Int)
    func sideBarWillClose()
    func sideBarWillOpen()

Comment: Then you have to implement all three of those in your view controller.